# Name for pair of functions

Tags: functions

If $f \circ g \circ f = f$ and $g \circ f \circ g = g$, $f$ and $g$ are functions, is there a name for $(f, g)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard them called [*quasi-inverses*](https://planetmath.org/QuasiinverseOfAFunction).

Comment: To add to this, if $f$ is a quasi-inverse of $g$, then $g$ isn't necessarily a quasi-inverse of $f$, so the OP's requirement is slightly more strict.

Comment: @Théophile I would say that "$f$ and $g$ are quasi-inverses of one another" gets around this. But certainly, you're right, "is a quasi-inverse of" is not a symmetric relation.